# Compare and Remove elements from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, compare, unique

What i need is to compare two different array where there is a common key.

I wrote a function that is doing what i need, but i would like to know if there is a fastest and clean way to have the same result.

here is my code:

Exemple of array:

First array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dafid] => daf_60304
            [title] => Hansel & Gretel - Cacciatori di streghe
            [creation] => 2018-09-01 00:02:25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dafid] => daf_115
            [title] => Il grande Lebowski
            [creation] => 2018-09-01 00:02:25
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [dafid] => daf_238636
            [title] => Anarchia - La notte del giudizio
            [creation] => 2018-09-01 00:02:25
        )
```

And here the 2nd array:

```
    Array
(       
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dafid] => daf_316727
            [title] => La notte del giudizio - Election Year
            [creation] => 2018-09-01 00:02:25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dafid] => daf_115
            [title] => Il grande Lebowski
            [creation] => 2018-09-01 00:02:25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [dafid] => daf_209112
            [title] => Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice
            [creation] => 2018-09-01 00:02:25
        )
```

And the result:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dafid] => daf_60304
            [title] => Hansel & Gretel - Cacciatori di streghe
            [creation] => 2018-09-01 00:02:25
        )  
    [1] => Array
        (
            [dafid] => daf_238636
            [title] => Anarchia - La notte del giudizio
            [creation] => 2018-09-01 00:02:25
        )
```

Result should be an array without the elements that have the same [dafid].
I got the result making this function, but I'm looking for a more clean solution.

```
function removeAlreadyDAF($array1,$array2) {
    $dafNextMovies = $array1;

    $dafDB = array2;

    foreach ($dafDB as $k => $v) {
        //$v['dafid']; //id release
        foreach ($dafNextMovies as $key => $value) {
            //loop release disponibili
            if ($value['dafid'] == $v['dafid']) {
                unset($dafNextMovies[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    $dafNextMovies = array_values($dafNextMovies);

    return $dafNextMovies;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this function : [array_udiff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php)

The third param how are you going to select element . It should be something like this. there is an exemple in comments. Check it  (function compare_names($a, $b))

```
private function compareData($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array easily from array intersec

```
$result_array = array_intersect_assoc($array1, $array2);
```

which does exactly what you want.